# sql date if not specify time will default refer to 00:00:00 or 23:59:59

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

for mysql datetime if I have variable date that not specify time will sql refer to ..

```
date >= date1 and date <= date2
```

so if date1 = '2015-01-01' 
      date2 = '2015-02-01'

will the result of my query be

**date >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'    and  <= '2015-02-01 23:59:59'**

or

**<= '2015-02-01 00:00:00'**

Comment: I apologize if this comes across as rude, but why don't you try it and find out for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be '2015-02-01 00:00:00'

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-type-conversion.html